# Determine if $x^2 \text{ and } 1-x^2$ is Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

In some home work I have to show if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable:

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2, x\geq0\\
1-x^2, x\lt 0
\end{cases}
$

I know that continuous functions are Borel but this is discontinuous at x=0.

(1) My idea was to say that $f^{-1}([0,1])=\{x: f(x) \in [0,1] \}$ gives me $[-1,0) \cup [0,1]=[-1,1]$ which is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

(2) Another approach could be to use same approach as [Showing that a discontinuous function is or is not borel measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264774/showing-that-a-discontinuous-function-is-or-is-not-borel-measurable)

However I have doubts if (1) is even allowed as an argument? And (2) seems to "easy"

Would appreciate input here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x^{2}I_A+(1-x^{2})I_B$ where $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty,0)$. Products and sums of Borel measurable functions are Borel measurable. Hence $f$ is a Borel measurable function.

Comment: Would the statement in bullet (1) also hold as an argument?

Comment: You are taking inverse image of one particular Borel set in 1). That is not enough to prove measurability.